# How to save OpenCV image with contour

Tags: python, opencv

I want to save image with contour

Here is my code:

```
img = cv2.imread('123.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, binary = cv2.threshold(gray, 150, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
image, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(binary, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for cnt in contours:
    # some code in here
    cv2.imwrite('234.jpg', cnt)
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried [the suggestions in this tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html)?

Comment: Hi Ken,
Yes, I have tried to draw the contour but I want to save the image with contour.

Comment: What does "save the image with contour" mean?

Comment: Hi Ken, I mean I want to discard the part of image outside the contour, sorry that my statement is ambiguous.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you want to do is to create a mask that you draw the contours on to, then use that to snip out the rest of the picture, or vice-versa. For instance, [based on this tutorial](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/02/09/removing-contours-image-using-python-opencv/):

```
(contours, _) = cv2.findContours(binary, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
mask = np.ones(img.shape[:2], dtype="uint8") * 255

# Draw the contours on the mask
cv2.drawContours(mask, contours, -1, 0, -1)

# remove the contours from the image and show the resulting images
img = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)
cv2.imshow("Mask", mask)
cv2.imshow("After", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: If you don't mind, can you explain why we are using a mask?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to save the contour as image is taking out its ROI(region of image) and saving it using imwrite() as follows -

First use cv2.boundingRect to get the bounding rectangle for a set of points (i.e. contours):

```
x, y, width, height = cv2.boundingRect(contours[i])
```

You can then use NumPy indexing to get your ROI from the image:

```
roi = img[y:y+height, x:x+width]
```

And save the ROI to a new file:

```
cv2.imwrite("roi.png", roi)
```

Comment: Yes the solution is good only if the shape is regular shape like square or rectangle and even circular to some extinct but not a good approach to deal with irregular shape pattern additional unwanted image area will be included in ROI

Answer (score 0):

I was trying many times and finally, I could make it:

```html
image= cv2.imread('muroprueba.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, binary = cv2.threshold(gray, 150, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
cnts, herarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cv2.drawContours(image,cnts,-1,(0,255,0),1)

cv2.imshow('image1',image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.imwrite('F:\caso1.jpg',image)            #Save the image
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```